# Close window that ignores WM_CLOSE?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I would like to close some application's windows from my app. I've tried to send `WM_CLOSE` message to that window (and it works perfectly for some windows), but some windows ignore `WM_CLOSE`. Then I've found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff381396(v=vs.85).aspx) article that says that if I want to close window, I could call `DestroyWindow` WINAPI function. But, according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx), "A thread cannot use `DestroyWindow` to destroy a window created by a different thread". So I can not use it from my app to close another app's window.

So my question is - is it possible to close application window, that ignores `WM_CLOSE` message? I do want exactly to close window (for example popup window), not to quit application, not to close thread related to that window and so on.

**EDIT**:
I know for sure, that window intentionally ignores my `WM_CLOSE`, as I see through spy++ that it receives my `WM_CLOSE` message. And I do not want to implement "clicking top right corner [X] button", as I want unified solution (the window with taht I have an issue does not have button [X] at all).

Answer (score 1):

`WM_CLOSE` is the standard way to close a window that follows standard rules.  Clearly your target window does not, so a standard solution will not work.

There is a possible alternative, though.  As you already discovered, only the thread that owns the window can destroy the window.  So you would have to make the owner thread destroy the window.  You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the target window's owning thread ID,    and then use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a thread-specific message hook into that thread (the hook callback must be implemented in a DLL), and then finally send a custom window message to the target window.  When the message hook receives the message, it will be running in tbe context of the window's owning thread, and thus can destroy the window.

Answer (score -2):

There's several reasons why the window is ignoring your WM_CLOSE:

1. The window might be intentionally ignoring `WM_CLOSE` because it's own logic deems that the window can not be closed. (e.g. it's still waiting for the user to enter text into all the edit fields). If you forced the window to close, you might cause undefined behavior in the app itself.
2. You didn't say how you were obtaining the window handle (HWND) in question.  That might be worth looking into, as your code could have a bug.

As a last resort, you could always implement code that moves the mouse cursor into the top right corner of the window and simulates a mouse click on top of the `[X]` close button.  Or click the window to bring it to the foreground and inject an `ALT+F4` keystroke via `SendInput`

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter.

1. I know for sure, that window intentionally ignores my `WM_CLOSE`, as I see through spy++ that it receives my `WM_CLOSE` message. This window does not have [X] close button in the right top corner, this window has its own button "Close" (not in the top right corner). But I want unified solution, that will work for all possible windows.

2. I am obtaining window handle through `SetWinEventHook` function (looking for `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` event). And I can verify handle is correct, as I also check this with spy++

Comment: Exactly, it's a custom window and has it's own logic for determining how to destroy itself. In this case, it's simple.  You need to simulate the user clicking that button.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what he didn't like?

Comment: @KtulhuGreen a solution that will work for "all possible windows" is not possible.

Comment: @selbie: Because your proposed solution not work for imaginary app that has custom drawn frame with illuminati symbol instead of close button, so clicking on this destroy the universe not close the app. Now seriously: If I remember correctly click on close button and/or pressing ALT+F4 sends WM_CLOSE message, so your proposed solution is "Instead of send WM_CLOSE, you must send WM_CLOSE."